# Failed to Fetch Using sudo apt-get update

Tags: jessie-lite

I have four raspberry pi 3's and each one is having the same problem. I have set all of them to a static ip from a tutorial. I have read many forum post about this and I have learned I am not able to contact the internet I only can ping computers and get a reply from my LAN. 
When i run **sudo apt-get update** I get the following error

```
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease

Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRe                 lease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease                  

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/Rele                 ase.gpg  Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gp                 g  Could not resolve 'archive.raspberrypi.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used                  instead.
```

When I ping **www.google.com** I get the following

```
pi@Rpi_2:~ $ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

The only config file I edited to get the static ip was **/etc/dhcpcd.conf**. I did this on each one. 
The config looks like this

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel
# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.254.170

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.254.160

static routers=192.168.254.254
static domain_name_servers=192.168.254.254
```

Comment: you don't appear to have set any DNS servers

Comment: I added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to the static domain_name_servers= . Do i need to also make changes to the /etc/network/interfaces file like in pre-jessie setups?

Comment: can you ping google by name (and have you rebooted after making the changes. If so you don't need to do anything more.

Comment: I did reboot after and I tried to ping www.google.com and google but same error saying unknown host

Comment: until you have it configured to resolve the name it won't work.

Comment: How would I configure it?

Comment: why do you need a static IP? Most people don't aand as you have discovered it is often not worth the effort.

Comment: I am setting up a cluster of Pi's and it would be nice to have a constant ip for them

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it thanks to google. I took one of the Pi's offline and re-installed the OS then I went and googled and found a better tutorial and its all working now. Somewhere along the way not exactly sure where I misconfigured something. A fresh start fixed it. BTW Thanks for your help Steve!